# Haskell, obtain a list of all enum values without naming them

Tags: haskell

I have this (and cannot be changed):

```
data Example = Value1 | Value2 | Value3
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Enum, Show)
```

And I need this function which returns the list of all values in the data definition:

```
examples :: [Example]
```

But I can't use the names of the values like this:

```
examples :: [Example]
examples = [Value1 ..]
```

I tried things like these, but they don't work:

```
examples :: [Example]
examples = [x | x <- Example]
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you don't have access to the constructors, then you need to use whatever functions are provided as an interface for `Example`. If you do actually have access to the constructors, use [StandaloneDeriving](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.3/html/users_guide/deriving.html#stand-alone-deriving)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Using `toEnum 0` to generate the first value, and `enumFrom` to then generate the list of values is the only way here without the `Bounded` class.

Eg:

```
generateEnumValues :: (Enum a) => [a]
generateEnumValues = enumFrom (toEnum 0)

examples :: [Example]
examples = generateEnumValues
```

The main issue with this approach is it isn't guaranteed that the `toEnum 0` will always give the first enum value (I don't see any such guarantee on the [Enum docs page](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#t:Enum)). However it will be true for any enum instance created with `deriving Enum`.

So if at all possible, add the `Bounded` class to the type, and just use `[minBound..]` instead.

Answer (score 21):

Derive `Bounded` and use `[minBound..maxBound]`.

Comment: I cannot change the data definition, hence cannot derive Bounded

Comment: You can use standalone deriving instead.